# Как можно "прижать" текст к внутренним границам span?

Tags: html, css, span

html:

```
<span id="head-1">101</span>
```

css:

```
font-family: HelveticaNeueCyrBlack;
font-size: 250px;
```

[image: результат в хроме]

Comment: `line-height: 250px;` пробовали?

Comment: Да. Это никак не влияет на текст в span. Я уже и шрифты менял на дефолт, но к сожалению...(

Comment: В ответе на вопрос я уточнил, что line-height должен быть 169, забыл что равный размеру шрифта, он не сработает как вам нужно

Answer (score 1):

Если для фиксированного текста(типа "101"), то можно использовать следующее:

```css
div {      
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div span {
  line-height: 169px;
  display: block;
  font-family: HelveticaNeueCyrBlack;  
  font-size: 250px;   
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>101</span>
</div>
```

Однако, если текст будет содержать выносной или свисающей элемент, то он обрежется:

```css
div {     
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div span {      
  display: block;
  font-family: HelveticaNeueCyrBlack;
  line-height: 169px;
  font-size: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>gef</span>
</div>
```

p.s. Про строение шрифта можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0),а [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-size) про font-size.

Comment: Опять магические числа... Можно просто задать `line-height: 169px;` тоже магия, но хоть без маргинов непонятных

Comment: DaemonHK, Спасибо!

Comment: Но это опять все зависит от конкретного шрифта, универсального решения тут вроде нет((